# how to store the twitter data which is extracted by using twitter4j api

Tags: java

front end tool:eclipse.
 To pull the twitter data i used twitter4j api.
how to store the collected tweets in excel sheets automatically.

please any one help me.
thanks in advance

Comment: The easiest way is to convert twitter4j result into csv, which is readable by excel.

Comment: how to convert twitter4j result to csv